# How to send a post request with a JSON string in Android using volley?

Tags: android, json, post, gson, android-volley

I'm new to sending post requests. I want to send an object in the form of a json string, how do I go about actually sending the json itself? I have this so far:

```
try {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    objInString = gson.toJson(obj);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//json request
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
}, new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
})
```

Comment: do it as `new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST, url, objInString,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){` or if `objInString` is String then use `new JSONObject(objInString)`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, my objInString is a string, what code do I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());   

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new  JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, jsonRequest,
    Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
            errorListener);
}

queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

If you have the data in string format which is json compatible, then convert it to JsonObject like below

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonRequest=new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a string, add it as a parameter in a POST request.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("json", someJsonString);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url, params,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
}, new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Then you can retrieve the string in your server by param name "json".